# Order of the growth of these expressions?

Tags: java, performance

I don't understand order of growth all that well, and I'm stuck on a book problem.  Any explanation or help would be greatly appreciated.  The question is:

For the following expressions, what is the order of the growth of each?

n^2 + 2n + 1

n^10 + 9n^9 + 20n^8 + 145n^7

(n + 1)^4

n + log(n)

(n^3 + 2n)/(n^2 + 0.75)

I didn't list all of them because I just want to get an idea or understand how to do them.  Thanks!

Comment: How is this related to Java? Is this part of an assignment? What have you tried yet?

Comment: It is related to sorting/searching, I don't even understand the question

Comment: Order of growth is the Highest *degree* in the polynomial equation.. Ignore everything else.. for example : `n^3+n^2-3` --> order of growth =`n^3`.Note that you need to actually *bring the equation to its simplest form* to get the answer in some cases

Comment: @Cara - `Log(n) < n`.. So...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about mathematics and has nothing to do with coding. On top of that it's a classic homework question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a table showing the Big-O complexities for each of your expressions.  I think this is what you want when you say "order of the growth of each":

```
Expression                      Complexity
------------------------------------------
n^2 + 2n + 1                    O(n^2)
n^10 + 9n^9 + 20n^8 + 145n^7    O(n^10)
(n + 1)^4                       O(n^4)
n + log(n)                      O(n)
(n^3 + 2n)/(n^2 + 0.75)         O(n)
```

One simple rule to keep in mind when computing Big-O complexities is what will happen to the expression as n approaches infinity.  For example, consider your first expression **n^2 + 2n + 1**.  When `n` becomes sufficiently large, the `n^2` term will dominate the behavior of the expression.

Comment: Good catch...didn't see the division sign.  I have updated my answer.